# Not able to add two arrays using np.insert()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Hey guys so I want to write a function that performs a z-score transformation to a single column in a 2d array and then return an array where the specified column is "transformed" and the other columns remain the same. So the way I went about this is first I deleted the column that I want to transform using `np.delete()`, then performed the transformation, and then finally added the array with the **deleted column** and the **transformed column** using `np.insert()`. However all the elements in the **transformed column**[image] is all 0. What can I do??

I have attached an image so you can view the incorrect output as well.

```
x1 = np.array([[4,3,12],[1,5,20],[1,2,3],[10,20,40],[7,2,44]])

def myfunc(array, scalar):
    total_result = np.delete(array, scalar, axis =1)
    z_score = ((array - array.mean())/array.std())[:,1]
    answer = np.insert(total_result, scalar, z_score, axis=1)
    return answer

myfunc(x1, 1)
```

Comment: A side question, but when you want to do a z-score transformation on a single column, do you want to use values from the whole matrix or just the column? Because `np.std()` and `np.mean()` calculate over the whole array, as per [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html), unless you specify `axis`.

Comment: Please consider accepting answers that resolve your issue in quesiton to close the question. Thank you.

Comment: I want to use values from the whole matrix. @AaronKeesing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is of type integer, and your z-score is float. When you insert float into an integer array, it converts it to integer, hence all 0. You need to convert your array into float first. Also, deleting/inserting is not the right way to do it, simply assign your new values to your desired column. No need for delete/insert. Here is how to do it:

```
def myfunc(array, scalar):
    z_score = ((array - array.mean())/array.std())[:,scalar]
    array[:,scalar] = z_score
    return array

x1 = x1.astype(np.float64, copy=False)
myfunc(x1, 1)
```

output:

```
[[ 4.         -0.64344154 12.        ]
 [ 1.         -0.49380397 20.        ]
 [ 1.         -0.71826033  3.        ]
 [10.          0.62847778 40.        ]
 [ 7.         -0.71826033 44.        ]]
```

Comment: Hey Ehsan this solution works, however when I run it twice/ or change the scalar parameter the previously transformed column remains unchanged.

Comment: @LordVoldemort Although it should work, you might need to assign your array to keep the changed values `x1=myfunc(x1, 1)` depending on your code. With this code, running your function twice should work. Again, please consider closing questions by accepting suitable answers.

Comment: Yeah its still not working, the column remains unchanged, when I run it 2 times.

Comment: @LordVoldemort there must be something different in your code than this. This code changes the array every time you run it. I cannot help further without more information on your code.

Comment: Hey Ehsan the code is working now, I used the astype() method inside the function.